# When i type forge init --force / forge init

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, foundry

It give this error :-
ZOE ERROR (from forge): zoeParseOptions: unknown option (--force)
ZOE library version 2013-02-16

it's snap error pre-installed in linux , so snap revokes foundry operation.

Anyone please help .
anvil is running
but not foundry command

I had removed snap package from bin also , but it giving error when i run foundry commands[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! Your second method successfully solved my problem!command as follows：

```
sudo -i
cd /bin/
rm forge
exit
```

That's all!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92839)

Answer (score 2):

OK i had find a way to this issue :-

1. add this in .bashrc or .zshrc alias forge='~/.foundry/bin/forge'
2. If you have installed snap just go /bin/ delete forge file

that's all

Answer (score 1):

can it be that you have installed a different forge cli? I've just googled and saw "forge - training program for SNAP". You can install The foundry forge cli following the foundry book: "https://book.getfoundry.sh/getting-started/installation"

Comment: foundryup same error .

Comment: thanks for your response . :)

Comment: Thank you, on Ubuntu 23.10, when I typed `forge` I also read `forge -trainging program for SNAP`. I already tried editiing the last line of `.bashrc` with `alias ..`, yet that did not work. After deleting the `/bin/forge` director using: `sudo -i` followed by `cd /bin/ && rm forge && exit`, I was able to reinstall (the right) `forge` using the command in the link you provided: `curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash`. Then, when I ran `forge`, it outputted `build`, `clean` etc. like it supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

i found the way like this

1. curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash
2. source /home/user/.zshenv
3. foundryup
4. forge